# How to store Key-Value pairs in a list or library in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to store unique key and value in my class component state(selectedFeatures) as a list of key-value pairs, by taking the arguments which are passed from the body. ex: {“user1”:"opt1", “user2”:"opt3"}.  The key must be unique, which means if the same key received from the body value should be updated to the relevant key which is stored previously

I did it in this way and it gives an error as “this.state.selectedFeatures is not iterable”. Therefore how to resolve this.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {features} from '../../services';

class UserData extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            featureTypes:[],
            selectedFeatures:{}
        }
    }


    getSelectedFeatures =(event,keyValue)=>{
        const features = {}; 
        features[keyValue] = event.target.value
        this.setState({selectedFeatures: features})
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        //http request from service component
        features().then(response => {
            this.setState({featureTypes:response})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)  
        })
    }


    render() {
        const {featureTypes} = this.state
        
        return (
            <div>
                {featureTypes.map((feature, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
            
                        <label>
                            <h4>
                                {feature.feature}
                            </h4>
                        </label>
        
                        <select
                            defaultValue="select-feature"
                            onChange={(event) => this.getSelectedFeatures(event, feature.feature)}>

                            {feature.types.map((type, i) => (
                                <option key={i} value={type}>
                                    {type}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UserData
```

Comment: `this.state.selectedFeatures is not iterable` doesn't seem to be caused by this portion of the code. Can you post the whole component, or at least where you call `getSelectedFeatures` please?

Comment: At least include the code where the error is being thrown. Where is the `this.state.selectedFeatures` that is being accessed? [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SinanYaman full code added

Comment: @DrewReese full code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without creating an array just simply adding to an object can be achieved via this method

```
  addTo = (event, val) => {
    this.setState((prev) => ({
      selectedFeatures: {
        ...prev.selectedFeatures,
        [event.target.value]: val
      }
    }));
  };
```

NOTE I changed the name from `getSelectedFeatures` to `addTo` from simplicity + because `get` would mean it returns something. In this case, you send and add it.

the `prev` is a previews state that was before the state change.

Also I went a step further and created a demo project https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-lake-4rvfz?file=/src/App.js

Inside of it there are multiple different containers that you may click and it will save what has been click as a `event.target` and a value they themself send to the method. If the container is clicked again OR a different but same type container is clicked, the value is overriten rather then added as a new parameter. Its constructed using `class`, as in your code. This is a simple quick demo that, after analizing, you may adapt to it as you wish with any code you want.